# Hash with array of hashes inside hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have a hash like this:

```
document = {
  "results" => {[
    {"ip" => 10, "host" => 12},
    {"ip" => 13, "host" => 17}
  ]}
}
```

It's a one item hash with an array of hashes inside the hash. I specified a value of `ip = 10`.

If the `ip` is more than `10`, I want to print both keys with values. This hash is very complicated and I don't know how to access these values. Can you help me?

Edit:
What if I had hash like this
`document = { "results" => [{"ip" => 10, "host" => 12, "temp" => yes},{"ip" => 13, "host" => 17, "temp" => yes}] }` and wanted print only ip and host after matching ip with 10?

Comment: Is there any reason you're using a hash?

Comment: That expression is invalid.

Comment: What @sawa is talking about is the `"results" => {[ hash, hash ]}` part. It should be `"results" => [ hash, hash ]`

Answer (score 1):

```
document["results"].each do |result|
  if result["ip"] > 10
    puts result # will print ip and host
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
document = { "results" => [{"ip" => 10, "host" => 12},{"ip" => 13, "host" => 17}] }

puts document['results'].select { |hash| hash['ip'] > 10 }
#=> {"ip"=>13, "host"=>17}
```

Explanation:

```
document['results']
```

returns the array of hashes:

```
[{"ip" => 10, "host" => 12},{"ip" => 13, "host" => 17}]
```

In the next step `select` is called on that returned array:

```
document['results'].select { |hash| hash['ip'] > 10 }
```

This returns all sub-hashes with an value `> 10` assigned to the key `'ip'`.

`puts` just prints the result to `STDOUT`

Comment: It works! Thanks :) Could You explain it to me step by step? I would like to understand it for the future.

Comment: @mila002 : Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have another problem today. Here is my code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

document = JSON.load File.new("hosts.txt")
file = JSON.load File.new("admins.txt")

first_table = document["results"]
second_table = file["admins"]
new_one = first_table | second_table
```

First hash looks like this:

```
document = { "results" => [{"ip" => 10, "host" => 12},{"ip" => 13, "host" => 17}] }
```

The second hash is

```
file = { "admins" => [{"host" => 12, "name" => 12},{"host" => 17, "name" => 17}] }
```

I want merge these two hashes matching them by host by the same value to get

```
{ "new_one" => [{"ip" => 10, "host" => 12, "name" => 12}, {"ip" => 13, "host" => 17}, "name" => 17]
```

When I try `new_one = first_table | second_table`it says test.rb:24:in `<main>': undefined method`|' for #Hash:0x00000002ca8be8 (NoMethodError) and when I try `new_one = first_table.merge(second_table)`its says test.rb:26:in `<main>': undefined method`merge' for #Array:0x00000002ce88b0(NoMethodError). So what is wrong with these hashes? One time they are hashes and the second time they are arrays? How to mach these hashes? The keys and values of host the same in both hashes.